# How to conditionally code a template function/class based on instantiation traits?

Tags: templates, c++17, instantiation

The example I'm providing is artificial and senseless but it is a reduction of a more complex (and more logic) code.

## Code

```
template<typename T>
void MyTemplate(T t) 
{
    wstringstream stringStream;
    stringStream << t << endl;

    // rest of the code
}

struct MyClass {};

void func()
{
    MyTemplate(1); // OK
    MyTemplate(MyClass()); // error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
}
```

## Problem

`MyTemplate` is generic but cannot compile with any instantiation.

## Question

Is there a way to code `MyTemplate` in the following manner:

```
void MyTemplate(T t) 
{
    wstringstream stringStream;

    // if/directives/magic to check if object is stream-able do
        stringStream << t << endl;
    // else
        stringStream << "object is not stream-able" << endl;

    // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: "Is there a way to code MyTemplate in the following manner" - The answer is "yes" (see phön's answer) because you tagged C++17 so you can use `if constexpr` (available starting from C++17). Before C++17 the answer is "no, not in the following matter" but you can use SFINAE to write two overloaded `MyTemplate()`, one for streamable types, one for non-stramable types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
First we need a trait to check if a given type is streamable to a given stream:

```
template<typename T, typename Stream, typename = void>
struct can_stream : std::false_type{};

template<typename T, typename Stream>
struct can_stream<T, Stream, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<Stream>() << std::declval<T>())>> : std::true_type{};
```

Having this in our toolbox, we can use if constexpr in our function:

```
template<typename T>
void MyTemplate(T t) 
{
    wstringstream stringStream;

    if constexpr(can_stream<T, std::wstringstream>::value)
    { 
        stringStream << t << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        stringStream << "object is not stream-able" << endl;
    }
}
```

And thats it.
It is good practice to provide a shorthand for the traitvalue:

```
template<typename T, typename Stream>
inline constexpr auto can_stream_v = can_stream<T, Stream>::value;
```

So we have our final working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename Stream, typename = void>
struct can_stream : std::false_type{};

template<typename T, typename Stream>
struct can_stream<T, Stream, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<Stream>() << std::declval<T>())>> : std::true_type{};

template<typename T, typename Stream>
inline constexpr auto can_stream_v = can_stream<T, Stream>::value;

template<typename T>
void MyTemplate(T t) 
{
    wstringstream stringStream;

    if constexpr(can_stream_v<T, std::wstringstream>)
    { 
        stringStream << t << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        stringStream << "object is not stream-able" << endl;
    }

    std::wcout << stringStream.str();
}

struct MyClass {};

int main()
{
    MyTemplate(1);
    MyTemplate(MyClass()); 
    return 0;
}
```